# Get content from subpages using HTML Agility Pack for WP8

Tags: c#, html, windows-phone-8, html-agility-pack

I've managed to parse HTML (content) from a newssite (ryfylke.net) and displayed it in my WP8-app. But how can i parse content from subpages (the "Read more" links)?
For now, when I click the links the app launches IE and displays the actual site. But what I would like to do is parse the content from the site and display it in the app.

EDIT (This is my current MainPage.xaml.cs)

```
        protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        string htmlPage = "";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            htmlPage = await client.GetStringAsync("http://ryfylke.net/kategori/nyheter/");
        }

        HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlPage);

        List<Nyheter> nyheter = new List<Nyheter>();
        foreach (var div in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//article[starts-with(@class, 'post-')]"))
        {
            Nyheter newNyheter = new Nyheter();
            newNyheter.Link = div.SelectSingleNode(".//a[@href]").Attributes["href"].Value;
            newNyheter.Bilde = div.SelectSingleNode(".//img[@class='attachment-entry-medium wp-post-image']").Attributes["src"].Value;
            newNyheter.Tittel = div.SelectSingleNode(".//h2[@class='entry-title entry-small-title']").InnerText.Trim();
            newNyheter.Sammendrag = div.SelectSingleNode(".//p[@class='entry-excerpt']").InnerText.Trim();
            nyheter.Add(newNyheter);
        }
        lstNyheter.ItemsSource = nyheter;
    }
```

And I then use public strings like this to use the content...

```
public string Bilde { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hi, I think you should update code of HTML Agility Pack as per your need.

Comment: Yes, but how to do it? :)